# Getting last element from a linked list C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to make a function that takes a pointer to the head of my linked list, then returns a pointer to the item at the end of the list, or if its empty, it will return `NULL`.

Here's what i have written so far:

```
MusicRec * getLastItem(MusicRec * theList)
{
MursicRec * currentElement;
currentElement = theList->next;
while(currentElement != NULL)
{
    theList = currentElement;
    currentElement = currentElement->next;
}

return(0);
}
```

The thing that I am confused about is what I need to return `theList` or `currentElement`?

Comment: `theList`, because `currentElement` is NULL after the loop

Comment: The last element would be stored in theList. currentElement will always be NULL.

Answer (score 7):

Try this :)

```
MusicRec  *getLastItem(MusicRec *theList)
{
    MursicRec  *currentElement;

    currentElement = theList;
    if (currentElement == NULL) // return NULL is list is empty cf (Captain girafe && learningC)
        return (NULL);
    while(currentElement->next != NULL) // check if next element is null then currentElement = next else return currentElement
      currentElement = currentElement->next;
    return (currentElement);
}
```

Comment: How would i go about returning NULL if the list is empty?

Comment: Will fail if `theList` is passed as `NULL` to the function

Comment: If you pass a `NULL` list, it will return `NULL`, pretty logic to me.

Answer (score 2):

you should return `theList`.
when loop ends `currentElement` is NULL. so `theList` will be pointing at the last node.
And make sure that `theList` received by the function is not NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive implementation of the same:

```
MusicRec  *getLastItem(MusicRec *theList)
{
    if (theList == NULL) // return NULL if list is empty
        return NULL;
    if (theList -> next == NULL) // return 1st element if it's a single element list
        return theList;
    return getLastItem(theList->next); // recurse
}
```